# Updating IndexedSeq[Vector] Scala functional programming

Tags: scala, vector, functional-programming

I'm trying to implement the Boids flocking algorithm in scala in order to learn and improve my functional programming.

I have run into a problem drawing a 'Canvas' on which the birds can move. I need to update the canvas with a "B" representing a boid whenever we print their position.

The Vector2D represents my own implementaion of a 2D Vector which simply contains an x and y position.

The following solution prints only the lines (ie Vectors) on which there is a boid, and repeats this for as many boids as there are. For instance if a list of 3 boids was passed to draw, then nine vectors would be created.

What is required is for canvas boundary amount of vectors to be created (10 in this case) which includes both the lines where there is a boid and those where there isnt.

In more generic form,I have a IndexedSeq of Vectors containing boundary.x amount of a certain value. What I need to do is update a Vector in the IndexedSeq at a certain position in that  vector. So if I need to update (1,1) then I would need to update the second vector in the sequence at it's position 1.

Theres a high chance I've missed something obvious so any help on the subject would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

David

```
object Canvas{

val boundary = Vector2D(10,10)
require(boundary.x == boundary.y)

    def draw(boids: List[Boid]) = {
        val lines = for{
          col <- 0 until boundary.x
          position <- boids.map(_.position)
        } yield Vector.fill(boundary.x)("* ").updated(position.x, "B   ")

        "\n" + (lines mkString "\n")
    }

}

case class Boid (position: Vector2D, velocity: Vector2D){
    def this() = this(Vector2D.random,Vector2D.random)
}

case class Vector2D(x: Int, y: Int)
```

Comment: Not sure what is the question here ... can you make it more generic without bringing the context of the algorithm you try to solve?

Comment: 1 - The code doesn't compile as is.  You might want to read up on creating [MCV examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 2 - After creating a compilable version of this code it is not clear what problem needs to be solved.

Comment: @marios 

The question has been updated. Hope this helps